# Remove a substring from the end of a dynamic URL

Tags: python-2.7

How can I remove a string of characters that follow the last forward slash(/) or back slash()?

For example these would be my inputs:

- 'C:/Users/BobDole/Documents/Python'
- 'C:/Users/Wendy/Pictures/WooHoo'
- '//Network/Data/Documents/Billy'

Here would be my desired outputs:

- 'C:/Users/BobDole/Documents/'
- 'C:/Users/Wendy/Pictures/'
- '//Network/Data/Documents/'

As you can see, there could be any number of forward/backslashes and the amount of characters following the final(far right) slash could be of any number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) the string on forward slashes, then [join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join) all but the last substring.

```
>>> s = 'C:/Users/BobDole/Documents/Python'
>>> '/'.join(s.split('/')[:-1])
'C:/Users/BobDole/Documents'
```

Or you could use [rfind](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rfind).

```
>>> s = 'C:/Users/BobDole/Documents/Python'
>>> s[:s.rfind('/')]
'C:/Users/BobDole/Documents'
```

In either case, if you need the trailing forward slash just add it with

```
>>> s += '/'
```

P.S. Those are file paths, not URLs

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for and yeah sorry I was actually referring to URLs but I gave an example using file paths because essentially file paths are URLs without the access method (http://, etc)

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to split the string into an array based on the delimiter of interest (here "/") and rejoin all but the last element

example:

```
'/'.join('/hello/there/friend'.split('/')[:-1])
```

and just replace '/hello/there/friend' with your preferred string or variable